# Need some help with a proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help again guys.

**Theorem:**  If $a$ is a real number, then $a\cdot 0 = 0$.

1. $a\cdot 0 + 0 = a\cdot 0$ (additive identity postulate)
2. $a\cdot 0 = a\cdot (0 + 0)$ (substitution principle)
3. $a\cdot(0 + 0) = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$ (distributive postulate)
4. $a\cdot 0 + 0 = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$ I'm lost here, wanna say its the transitive
5. $0 + a\cdot 0 = a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$ (commutative postulate of addition)
6. $0 = a\cdot 0$ (cancellation property of addition)
7. $a\cdot 0 = 0$ (symmetric postulate)

So I'm not sure what to put down for the 4th step. The theorem and proof were given and I had to list the postulates for each step.

Comment: You want to explain step $4$?  String together the first three:  $a*0+0=a*0=a*(0+0)=a*0+a*0$.  So it's just the transitive property of equality.

Comment: By induction, transitivity implies that if $a_0 = a_1$ and $a_1=a_2$ and... and $a_i=a_{i+1}$ for each $i\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ (*on up to $a_{n-1}=a_n$*) then you have that $a_0=a_n$.  Transitivity, although often worded as working with just three things, can be used to string several more than just three things together.

Comment: You need help *again*?  This is the only question you've asked.  If you have multiple (unregistered) accounts, you may do well to register one of them and look into merging the others into it.

Answer (score 2):

Just put steps $1, 2$ and $3$ together and you obtain step $4$. Exactly as in @lulu's comment:
$$a\cdot 0+0=a\cdot 0=a\cdot(0+0)=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0.$$

Comment: Well it looks like the Transitive postulate to me but, there are more than three steps. Is that possible with the transitive postulate?

Comment: of course it is. $a=b \land b=c\Rightarrow a=c$, but if also $c=d$ then again by the transitive postulate $a=c \land c=d \Rightarrow a=d$

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 (not 5) is the one you are confused on.  And it is indeed the transitive property of equality.

But step 2 actually skips a step and is not at all the associattive postulate.  You should first say $0 = 0+0$ (additive identity) then (2) follows by substitution.

Answer (score 0):

After the 4th step: use the existence of an additive inverse for $\;a\cdot0\;$ , and add it to both sides:

$$4)\;a\cdot0=a\cdot0+a\cdot0\implies a\cdot0+(-a\cdot0)=a\cdot0+a\cdot0+(-a\cdot 0)$$

Use now associativity of addition on the right, and the meaning of additive inverse on the left:

$$0=a\cdot0+\left(a\cdot0+(-a\cdot0\right))\implies 0=a\cdot0+0=a\cdot0$$

and we're done.